# How to detect which network interface received UDP packet using c++ in windows 7?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, udp, winsock

I have a Windows 7 machine with 3 Ethernet interfaces.

I created a UDP Socket and bound to INADDR_ANY. When the socket receives a broadcast UDP packet, how to know which network interface received the packets?

I need to get IP address corresponding to the network interface also?

Answer (score -2):

Check out Wireshark:

https://www.wireshark.org/

From Wireshark about their product:

> "Wireshark is the world's foremost network protocol analyzer. It lets you see what's happening on your network at a microscopic level. It is the de facto (and often de jure) standard across many industries and educational institutions."